# RSS feed to chart

Tags: rss, charts

I would like to know if there is any way or any tool out there which can display interactive charts (ie.flash) by using RSS feeds as data? I know I can use Excel data to make charts but what about rss feed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be possible to make charts from an RSS feed, but it really depends on the data you're trying to graph. You could use XSLT to transform the RSS XML into an HTML chart. You could also deserialize the RSS XML into an object list and use a charting library such as Google charting. These are just some options. What kind of data are you trying to graph? There may be a public API for obtaining this data rather than using an RSS feed.

Comment: Basically all I need is a number of daily posts, like blog posts, twitter posts etc.

Comment: Do you have a link to a sample feed that you would like to retrieve data from? I can help you with XSLT once I see the XML of the RSS feed.

Comment: ie. http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=twitter or http://api2.socialmention.com/search?q=twitter&src[0]=facebook&f=rss

Comment: Do you have a particular language that you'll be using for drawing the charts?

Comment: No. That is why I am looking for most simple and effective solution out there. There are many services out there (ie. Google charts etc.) but none of them can't use RSS as data.

Comment: I don't believe that without using some sort of server side/client side scripting language you'll be able to make charts from RSS feeds. You could use PHP or JavaScript as the RSS parser and generate charts using Google Charts from the data returned from the parsed RSS. There are other options for scripting as well. It really depends on what web hosting setup you have available. Also, if you go the XSLT route, you'll still need a scripting language do do the translations on the RSS.